# Find best combination of X reference items to fullfill maximum number of order

Tags: algorithm, optimization, greedy

With this example
`order_book = [ {"id": 1, "reference_items": ["item1", "item2", "item4"]}, {"id": 2, "reference_items": ["item1", "item4", "item5"]}, {"id": 3, "reference_items": ["item2", "item3", "item4"]}, {"id": 4, "reference_items": ["item2", "item1"]}, {"id": 5, "reference_items": ["item2", "item4"]}, {"id": 6, "reference_items": ["item1"], {"id": 7, "reference_items": ["item2"], {"id": 8, "reference_items": ["item7"]} ]`

Best combination of 1 reference items: ('item1'), can fulfill 1 orders completely (Order 6) .
Best combination of 2 reference items: ('item1', 'item2'), can fulfill 3 orders completely (Order 4,6,7).
Best combination of 3 reference items: ('item1', 'item2', 'item4'), can fulfill 5 orders completely (Order 1,4,5,6,7)
Best combination of 4 reference items: ('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'), can fulfill 6 orders completely (Order 1,3,4,5,6,7)
Best combination of 5 reference items: ('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'), can fulfill 7 orders completely (Order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Best combination of 6 reference items: ('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item7'), can fulfill 8 orders completely (Order 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

I want to find the best combination of 1 reference items to fulfill the maximum number of orders completely, 2  references items to fulfill the maximum number of orders completely, etc.

May be a greedy algorithm approach ?

Answer (score 0):

from ite

```
rtools import combinations

def max_orders_with_distinct_refs(order_book, num_distinct_refs):
    # get all unique reference items in the order book
    all_refs = set()
    for order in order_book:
        all_refs.update(order["reference_items"])

    # generate all possible combinations of distinct reference items
    ref_combinations = combinations(all_refs, num_distinct_refs)

    # count how many orders can be entirely completed with each reference item combination
    orders_completed = {}
    for refs in ref_combinations:
        orders_completed[refs] = 0
        for order in order_book:
            if set(order["reference_items"]) <= set(refs):
                orders_completed[refs] += 1

    # find the reference item combination with the most completed orders
    best_ref_combination, max_num_orders = max(orders_completed.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    best_order_ids = [order["id"] for order in order_book if set(order["reference_items"]) <= set(best_ref_combination)]

    return max_num_orders, best_order_ids, list(best_ref_combination)

order_book = [
    {"id": 1, "reference_items": ["item1", "item2", "item4"]},
    {"id": 2, "reference_items": ["item1", "item4", "item5"]},
    {"id": 3, "reference_items": ["item2", "item3", "item4"]},
    {"id": 4, "reference_items": ["item2", "item1"]},
    {"id": 5, "reference_items": ["item2", "item4"]},
    {"id": 6, "reference_items": ["item1"]},
    {"id": 7, "reference_items": ["item2"]},
    {"id": 8, "reference_items": ["item7"]},
    {"id": 9, "reference_items": ["item1"]},
]

num_distinct_refs = 2

max_num_orders, best_order_ids, best_ref_combination = max_orders_with_distinct_refs(order_book, num_distinct_refs)

print(f"Maximum number of orders that can be entirely completed with {num_distinct_refs} distinct reference items: {max_num_orders}")
print(f"Order IDs: {best_order_ids}")
print(f"Reference item combination: {best_ref_combination}")
```

In python